# How to find their final speed in terms of their masses?

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

The answer is $\frac{1}{m_1}$ and $\frac{1}{m_2}$.

I used the conservation of momentum (taking into consideration initial momentum is zero) , coefficient of restitution , and conservation of kinetic energy (since it is elastic collision) and did not approach to a solution.

Comment: just to clarify, the answers should be $\frac{I}{m_1}$ and $\frac{I}{m_2}$

Comment: I made some minor edits, but much needs to be done to bring the Question up to the site standards.  Please review [ask].  The body of your Question should give a reasonably complete statement of the problem you want help with, and putting it in your own words will help Readers to understand where you are having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usual notation, by conservation of momentum, $$0=m_1u_1-m_2u_2=-m_1v_1+m_2v_2$$
And by Newton's Law of Restitution, $$u_1+u_2=v_1+v_2$$

Eliminating $v_1$ gives $$v_2=\frac{m_{1} u_{1}+m_{1} u_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$$
$$=\frac{I+m_1\frac{I}{m_2}}{m_1+m_2}$$
$$=\frac{I}{m_2}$$

Similarly for $v_1$.

Comment: How do you know that restitution is 1??

Comment: The question says the collision is perfectly elastic, so the coefficient of restitution is $1$

Comment: That seems more logical for me now